# How to get a bot to send a message automatically?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a question; that's as to how to make a discord.py bot send a message by itself upon on_ready(): ?
Its only in one server and it doesn't matter what channel at the moment, i couldn't find anything in the documentation-
any help is appreciated ^^!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   await client.get_channel("enter channel id here").send("bot is online")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `on_ready` object has access to send. So I don't think it is possible via the `on_ready` object. You would have to set it via a different action.

Comment: It an event correct, but provided you fetch a sendable as seen above it should be gucci

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Sendchannel = channel Id

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  channel = bot.get_channel(Sendchannel)
  await channel.send(“text”)
```

For more check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TZ3CF7yXfc) at 12:50 (for the YouTube video not real time)